# How to make a class append a new file based on the date?

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging, sensors

I'm running a really basic DHT22 temp/humidity sensor with python3 on a really old pizero, simple as can be with some tutorial python3 and a simple logger.

so it outputs to terminal and appends/logs to a file with the name based on the day/month/year, all is working well, except when the day changes, it keeps logging to the old file name,

I can't work out how to get it to update the filename when the day changes, and all the other methods of logging get really REALLY complicated for the basic setup I'm running

its a basic dump to log file dump into the terminal window setup

I've never messed with python3 before, last time I did any script/code was 15 years ago for a microcontroller, and things don't behave the same way in python3 at all, I feel like its something simple(tried to make the self.log = open into a loop, tried to get my sensor while loop to update the lol variable every time it reads from the sensor, none of those worked.

```
lol = datetime.datetime.now()

class Logger(object):
     def __init__(self):
        self.terminal = sys.stdout
        self.log = open("dailytemplog%s.%s.%s.log" % (lol.day,lol.month,lol.year), "a")

     def write(self, message):
        self.terminal.write(message)
        self.log.write(message)

     def flush(self):
        # this flush method is needed for python 3 compatibility.
        # this handles the flush command by doing nothing.
        # you might want to specify some extra behavior here.
        pass

sys.stdout = Logger()
```

And the while loop for the sensor incase thats useful for any reason:

```
while True:
    try:
         # Print the values to the serial port
         lol = datetime.datetime.now()
         temperature_c = dhtDevice.temperature
         temperature_f = temperature_c * (9 / 5) + 32
         humidity = dhtDevice.humidity
         print("Current Date and time: %s/%s/%s %s:%s:%s" % (lol.day, lol.month, lol.year, lol.hour, lol.minute, lol.second))
         print("Temp: {:.1f} F / {:.1f} C    Humidity: {}% "
               .format(temperature_f, temperature_c, humidity))
    except RuntimeError as error:     # Errors happen fairly often, DHT's are hard to read, just keep going
         pass

    time.sleep(5.0)
```

I tried updating the lol variable with the loop, didn't work I assume because self.log gets the name/variable only once, tried adding the log open/append section to a loop, failed at that (don't think I can add part of a class to a loop and have it work)

tried looking for other logging methods, all are way too complicated for something as simple as dumping output to a file(they have tiers such as debug/info/warning/etc etc)

I was expecting as the self.log = open("dailytemplog%s.%s.%s.log" % (lol.day,lol.month,lol.year), "a") opened the file to append the next part, it would change the day number as the next day rolled round making/appending a new file but it seems it checks the lol variable once per run and never checks again for additional appends/opens

Comment: You create a string, `"dailytemplog%s.%s.%s.log" % (lol.day,lol.month,lol.year` *once* then pass that string to `open`. You only ever create one file object.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to use [TimedRotatingFileHandler](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.handlers.html#logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler), along with a [StreamHandler](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.handlers.html#streamhandler) to log to console as well.

With TimedRotatingFileHandler, we can configure the Type and Duration of interval, but the time will be added as a suffix to the old log file and current log file will not have any time suffix.

Example:

```
log.log
log.log.2024-01-19
```

If you want to have the time as suffix before the extention, and the current running log also to have the suffix, you would need to build a custom handler like this.

```
import logging
from logging.handlers import TimedRotatingFileHandler
import datetime
import os


class CustomTimedRotatingFileHandler(TimedRotatingFileHandler):
    def __init__(self, filename, when='D', interval=1, backupCount=0, encoding=None, delay=False, utc=False):
        self.filename = '.'.join(filename.split('.')[:-1])
        self.file_ext = filename.split('.')[-1]
        self.set_basefile_name()
        super().__init__(self.baseFilename, when, interval, backupCount, encoding, delay, utc)

    def set_basefile_name(self):
        self.baseFilename = f"{self.filename}_{datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')}.{self.file_ext}"

    def doRollover(self):
        if self.stream:
            self.stream.close()
            self.stream = None
        self.set_basefile_name()
        if self.backupCount > 0:
            for s in self.getFilesToDelete():
                os.remove(s)
        if not self.delay:
            self.stream = self._open()


# Create a logger
logger = logging.getLogger('my_logger')
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

# Create a formatter with a date and time prefix
log_formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s', datefmt='%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S')

# Create a StreamHandler (for console) and set the formatter
console_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
console_handler.setFormatter(log_formatter)

# Create a CustomTimedRotatingFileHandler and set the formatter
log_file = 'logs/log.log'
os.makedirs('logs', exist_ok=True)
file_handler = CustomTimedRotatingFileHandler(log_file, when="D", interval=1, backupCount=0)
file_handler.setFormatter(log_formatter)

# Add both handlers to the logger
logger.addHandler(console_handler)
logger.addHandler(file_handler)

# Log some messages
logger.debug('This is a debug message')
logger.info('This is an info message')
logger.warning('This is a warning message')
logger.error('This is an error message')
logger.critical('This is a critical message')
```

I have tested the logger with rotation every second and it worked while printing to console as well.
[image]